# Tkinter Equivalent of PqQt's sender()

Tags: python, tkinter

As the title states, is there an equivalent to sender() in TKinter? I'd like to call one function with two buttons (accept/cancel) and handle to slight difference in functionality with an if-statement, rather than creating two functions which are 90% identical.

Comment: You can pass in arguments when you assign a function to a tkinter button by making it a lambda function

Comment: You can call a function with two buttons. `btn1 = Button(root, command=fun1)``btn2=Button(root, command=fun2)`